Display mat table cell text as hyperlink or text based on another value from API response
I am new to angular. I have a material table that is populated based on API response. The API response has employee number and isactive data. I want to display the mat cell text as hyperlink based on isactive status. so if isactive=y then the employee number should display as hyperlink else it should display only as text.
<ng-container matColumnDef="Employeenum">
  <th <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{"Employee num#"}}</th>
  <td mat-cell data-label="Employee num#" *matCellDef="Let emp">
    <a tabindex="0" role="link" attr.arial-label="Link for employee number{{emp.empno}}" href="www.abc.com/{{emp.empno}}" target="_blank">{{emp.empno}}</a>
  </td>
</ng-container>

I tried using *ngif
<ng-container matColumnDef="Employeenum">
  <th <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{"Employee num#"}}</th>
  <ng-container *ngIf="emp.isactive=y ; else notactive">
    <td mat-cell data-label="Employee num#" *matCellDef="Let emp">
      <a tabindex="0" role="link" attr.arial-label="Link for employee number{{emp.empno}}" href="www.abc.com/{{emp.empno}}" target="_blank">{{emp.empno}}</a>
    </td>
    <ng-template #notactive>
      <td mat-cell data-label="Employee num#" *matCellDef="Let emp">{{emp.empno}}
      </td>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>

but this is not working.

There are a few errors in your column:

Accessing the emp variable before declaration with let emp.

Typo error for Let emp, should be let instead of Let.

Typo error for <mat-header-cell in <th> element.

Comparing emp.isactive=y with the assignment (operator) and y variable? Believe that you want to compare the character: emp.isactive == 'y'.

Should wrap the *ngIfElse container and template within the <td> element.


Once you fix those errors, the "Employeenum" should be as below:
<ng-container matColumnDef="Employeenum">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{"Employee num#"}}</th>
  <td mat-cell data-label="Employee num#" *matCellDef="let emp">
    <ng-container *ngIf="emp.isactive == 'y'; else notactive">
      <a
        tabindex="0"
        role="link"
        attr.arial-label="Link for employee number{{emp.empno}}"
        href="www.abc.com/{{emp.empno}}"
        target="_blank"
        >{{emp.empno}}</a
      >
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #notactive> {{emp.empno}} </ng-template>
  </td>
</ng-container>

Demo @ StackBlitz
